# SCXML notation of a target set

Tags: scxml

How can I define a "legal state configuration" according to https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#LegalStateConfigurations. I want to specify a target set (!), not a single target. Target sets can be defined inside the `initial` attribute of the `<scxml>` and `<state>` elements, as well as a `target` attribute of `<transition>` elements. But I can't seem to find any example of the notation of more than one state inside the above-mentioned attributes. Do they have to be space-separated? Or array notation according to JavaScript? Or object notation? Or comma-separated?
Thanks for any hints.

But anyway I'd like to know, what I have missed in the standard, to be sure to be interpreter-independent.

Here's a little testcode:

```
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0">
    <initial>
        <transition target="State_3_2 State_4_2" />
    </initial>
    <parallel id="Parallel_1">
        <history id="hist" type="deep">
            <transition target="State_1_2 State_2_2" />
        </history>
        <state id="State_1">
            <state id="State_1_1" />
            <state id="State_1_2" />
        </state>
        <state id="State_2">
            <state id="State_2_1" />
            <state id="State_2_2" />
        </state>
    </parallel>
    <parallel id="Parallel_2">
        <transition target="hist" event="switch_hist" />
        <state id="State_3">
            <state id="State_3_1" />
            <state id="State_3_2" />
        </state>
        <state id="State_4">
            <state id="State_4_1" />
            <state id="State_4_2" />
        </state>
    </parallel>
</scxml>
```

To test: on entry, the states `State_3_2` and `State_4_2` must be active (`initial` element executed correctly), after event `switch_hist`, states `State_1_2` and `State_2_2` must be active (`transition`attribute executed correctly).
If somebody has an interpreter all set other than SCION, could You test this there?
Also the alternative syntax with the first 4 lines replaced by

```
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0" initial="State_3_2 State_4_2">
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It is space-separated. You can see an example of this in the [SCXML test test suite](https://www.w3.org/Voice/2013/scxml-irp/). For example line 9 of [test364](https://www.w3.org/Voice/2013/scxml-irp/364/test364.txml).

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thank You. SCION shows correct behaviour for this. But how about having a target set inside the `initial` _attribute_, i.e. inside the `<scxml>` tag? Here, SCION fails.

Comment: This is a known issue in SCION: https://github.com/jbeard4/SCION/issues/390 Should be fixed soon.